# Divs created by ng-repeat do not auto-fit to content width when inside an accordion

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, accordion

I am attempting to use angularJS to print out some data. Here is a relevant segment of the script:

```
$scope.incidentCats = [{
  name: "FIRE",
  incidents: [{
    location: "location 1",
    dateTime: "datetime 1",
    currStatus: "currStatus 1"
  },
  {
    location: "location 2",
    dateTime: "datetime 2",
    currStatus: "currStatus 2"
  }]
},
{
  name: "CODE BLUE",
  incidents: [{
    location: "location 3",
    dateTime: "datetime 3",
    currStatus: "currStatus 3"
  }]
}];

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#accordion").accordion({
    header: ".category",
    collapsible: true,
    active: false
  });
});
```

As you can see in the data, incident type `FIRE` has records of two incidents, while incident type `CODE BLUE` has only one.

Here's the relevant code in the EJS file:

```
<div id="accordion" class="container">
  <div ng-repeat="category in incidentCats" class="incident">
    <header class="category">
      <strong>{{ category.name }}</strong>
    </header>
    <section>
      <div ng-repeat="incident in category.incidents">
        {{ incident.location }}<br>
        {{ incident.dateTime }}<br>
        {{ incident.currStatus }}<br>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Finally, here's my CSS for this particular section of the HTML (excluding any common CSS used for the whole project that is out of my hands):

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 25px;
}

.incident {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 25px 0;
}

.incident section {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.incident section > div {
  margin: 5px auto;
}
```

The height of the `section` element for `FIRE`, which has two inner `div` elements for the two incidents, and the height of that for `CODE BLUE`, which has only one `div` for one incident, are the same. As a result, while the `FIRE` incidents fill out its section on the web page, the `CODE BLUE` section has a large empty space where the non-existent second incident would have been.

That is not what I want, which is for the height of each incident category to fit its respective content. I have tested my code and observed that the sections do fit their content when the accordion code is removed. As such, it's most likely the accordion that is causing the issue. Is it possible to rectify this, such that I have an accordion implemented while having each section fit its contents' height, and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#accordion").accordion({
    header: ".category",
    collapsible: true,
    active: false,
    heightStyle : "content"
  });
});
```

This will solve your problem.